# How to redirect URL in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I created my website using PHP before so that all the page urls extensions are ended up with php extension like  `www.example.com/about-us.php` and I shared that urls in some other places.

But now I am creating that site in wordpress so all the urls are like  `www.example.com/about-us`

Now how can I redirect www.example.com/about-us.php to www.example.com/about-us

Comment: it is some related the apache handler ,that removing .php extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule **just below RewriteBase line** in WP's .htaccess file to redirect `.php` links:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule !(^|/)wp-login\.php$ /%1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: how to allow wp-login.php also in that

Comment: anubhava no success, url.com/wp-login.php redirecting to url.com/wp-login which return page not found

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like,goto admin panel and click on `permalinks` under `settings`.Then you notice options for Url settings.As per your need you need to select `Post name` and then your all URLs will like as your deserve(www.example.com/about-us)

Comment: I created pages in that format only but now I need redirection from about-us.php which I shared the details outside